# Popup After Pressing TabBar Item

Tags: swift, swift3, popup, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `tabbar` with 5 items. **I am trying to have a popup come up if the user presses the third object. This popup will go over their current screen and not move them to another screen.** Then once the user presses on one of the popup options it will move them to the next screen. Or they can press outside the popups and they will close.

I am not sure out to do this. I have attached an image below to should you what I am trying to get (the popups have the red boxes around them). **How do I implement this?** [image]

///EDIT/// The function TabBar shouldSelect method seems like something I should use but when I try implementing it with a simple print statement when it's pressed is not working.

Comment: make an investigation for existing solutions first.
I recommend this site https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=tabbar
Then, please ask concrete questions

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to use Action sheets instead of a popover with two buttons.

Make an outlet from tab bar item 3 to your ViewController, make sure you set the Connection as an Action, give the function a name, for this example I will call it "presentCameraAndPhotos"

```
@IBAction func presentCameraAndPhotos(_ sender: Any) {
      var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Foo", message: "Bar", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { _ in
        //Do whatever it is you want to do when camera is selected 
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "CameraVCSegueID", sender: self)
    })

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photos", style: .default) { _ in
        //Do whatever it is you want to do when photos is selected
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "PhotoVCSegueID", sender: self)
    })

   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

  present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Don't forget to prepare the segues.

If this is for the iPad, set an outlet for the tab bar 3 item in the VC and use something like this instead :

```
@IBAction func presentCameraAndPhotos(_ sender: Any) {
      var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Foo", message: "Bar", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { _ in
        //Do whatever it is you want to do when camera is selected 
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "CameraVCSegueID", sender: self)
    })

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photos", style: .default) { _ in
        //Do whatever it is you want to do when photos is selected
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "PhotoVCSegueID", sender: self)
    })

   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

  alert.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover 
  let popoverPresentation = alert.popoverPresentationController
  popoverPresentation.barButtonItem = //Whatever the outlet name of your tab bar 3 is 
  present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: is there a way to get this in the style I want (in the picture)?

Comment: I tried implementing your code, but the type of connection I can make with a tabbar item is either an Outlet or Outlet Connection. It does not let me have an Action as a option

Comment: It has to be a bar button item, you may have to drag it from the document outline to make the connection.

Comment: What do you mean by "the document outline"?